# How to convert a relation of one form into another in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a relation

B of the form {A::id:int, A::date:chararray}

C is of the form {id:int, date:chararray}

I want to convert B into C i.e. B' Schema should be id:int, date:chararray

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Please refer to the Pig documentation and describe what is unclear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
C2 = foreach B generate
  A::id as id,
  A::date as date;
```

Answer (score 0):

The schema of B and C is already the same -  both have an int followed by a chararray. if you want to rename the fields you can do the projection suggested by user2303197